# sql server 2008: configuration information

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-connectivity

I have sql server 2008 installed on my dev machine. How I figure out things like, the name of the server, do I connect to it using windows auth or using sql auth. If I connect using sql auth what is my account information. I set it up a while back and I dont know how to read all the sql server install and configuration information. I am trying to install Vault and its trying to connect to sql server and I dont know things like sql server name, login credentials on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your local machine can be specified as `(local)` or `localhost` or even just `.` (a period) as the SQL Server (machine) name.

If you can connect to SQL Server using Windows auth - that's probably the easiest way to go. So just try if that works, and if it does - perfect!

Otherwise, you need to find out what your `sa` (system administrator) account on your local server uses as a password - that's your key to everything, basically. If you don't know that password anymore.... you might need to reinstall SQL Server to get that password back.